# Ubuntu 16.04 Core OS snap won't remove

Tags: package-management, 16.04, snap

So I tried to install ubuntu calculator app snap package. The process went fine and after logging out and back in I managed to start the app from the menu. After that I decided to play with snap commands and removed the calculator app. The app was removed without issues but the ubuntu-core snap was still there. I tried to remove that snap with "sudo snap remove" command and got an error. After checking the snap history I've seen the status of this action was "hold".

So my question is: is this by design? Can the ubuntu-core snap be removed at all? Also is there a need to perform "apt-get autoremove/autoclean" after removing a snap. If yes then what are the commands to do that?

Thank You

Comment: Same here. If you open up System Monitor > File Systems, it shows to remain mounted as a file system as well (after reboot).

Comment: I managed to disable the mounting of `ubuntu-core` with this command `sudo systemctl disable snap-ubuntu\\x2dcore-122.mount`

Answer (score 7):

You can't remove the ubuntu-core snap using the snap command, no. If you really want to remove it, remove the snapd package itself and then remove the `/var/lib/snapd` directory (if it says it's still in use, unmount the snap and try again).

Answer (score 1):

In my case,I found [this page at ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328152).

So I simply executed this line-command:

```
sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools
```

Comment: This worked for me, and automatically unmounted any current snap mounts and removed their fstab files from `/run/snapd` and `/var/lib/snapd`.

Comment: Does this also remove any preinstalled-by-default snaps, if there are any, from disk?